# Directing users to facebook login page without asking for permissions

Tags: facebook, permissions, oauth, facebook-fbml

I'm trying to redirect users to the facebook login page then back to my app without the Log In to app page displaying. Is this possible?

I've looked into the "next" parameter which is automatically generated by the PHP-SDK but cannot seem to change it.

Is there anyway to do what I'm looking for? I want to make sure users are logged in in order to check to see if they have authed my app but do not want them to if they are not already.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: can you show here, the code of the SDK where you see the "next" parameter being generated?

Comment: $facebook->getLoginURL($params)

Comment: The next parameter is set to "https%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2Fdialog%2Fpermissions.request%3F_path%3Dpermissions.request%26app_id%..." which seems like it can be overwritten.

Comment: Ok so i have checked all the possiblities, i think. And you can't do what you are trying to do, check my answer.hope it helps:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, i don't think it is possible to modify the **next** parameter. The only place where i saw the next parameter(in the PHP SDK) is in the `getLogoutUrl()` function, as seen in the source of the **base_facebook.php**. And that parameter defines which url to go, after logout.
For `getLoginUrl()` in the **base_facebook.php** file, we have

```
 return $this->getUrl(
  'www',
  'dialog/oauth',
  array_merge(array(
                'client_id' => $this->getAppId(),
                'redirect_uri' => $currentUrl, // possibly overwritten
                'state' => $this->state),
              $params));
```

as the last line in the function, which obviously means that the oauth-dialog will be shown, no matter what you try.
If your app is not on Facebook, then you can go for `<fb:login-button>Login with Facebook</fb:login-button>` in Javascript, and subsequently follow the example from [this url](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/guides/web/#login). You'll see there that it's **not possible to remove that dialog entirely**, even if you don't ask for any permissions.
The Javascript SDK's FB.login() method will also bring up the auth dialog.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for looking into it. I'm going to leave the question open for a couple more days and see if anyone else has a work-around or something.

Comment: Hey, glad i could help in someway, if you figure out your own hack, do post it here.

Answer (score 2):

They have to accept permissions for the first time only. Facebook will never let you to get user's data without their knowledge/accept

Comment: I don't want to get ANY data from the user, only allow them to login the redirect to my app's urls.

Comment: @Derek: you're getting basic data when offering to log them in

Comment: But... I have no need for basic data. It seems like this can be done by specifying the "next" parameter but I cannot figure out how to do that using the PHP-SDKs $facebook->getLoginURL($params) function.

Comment: @Derek: You can't login without user allowing you to get you their basic data. They're basic and they're given always automatically

Comment: you need their facebook id to log them in to your site. Facebook id is part of basic data. You do need it :)

Comment: I can check to see if a user is logged into facebook using FB.getLoginStatus whether or not the user has approved my app. If they are not logged in I simply want direct them to the facebook login page then back to my app. My app doesn't even want their facebook ID at this point and I have no desire for require a user to Login to my app. It's just a page that my client is asking be removed and from a developers perspective it serves no purpose.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using php :

```
// Create our Application instance.
$facebook = new Facebook(array(
  'appId'  => $fbconfig['appid'],
  'secret' => $fbconfig['secret'],
  'cookie' => true
));

//Facebook Authentication part
$user = $facebook->getUser();

if (!$user) {
    // user is not logged on --> redirect to the login url
} else {
    // user is logged on you can do what you want
}
```

Comment: This would check to see if my app has been allowed by a logged in facebook user. This is not what I'm looking for. I'm trying to link to the login page after generating the facebook login url ($facebook->getLoginUrl($params)) without requiring the user to auth my app after redirecting. I see that the next parameter is set but cannot seem to change or remove it.